# two database connection: php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I have two databases in same server with same username and pass. Right now I am connecting to only one database, but I would like to connect to both.

For now this is my code, whick connect only to one database:

connect1.php

```
<?
$servername='localhost';

$dbusername='user';
$dbpassword='pass';

$dbname1='db1';
$dbname2='db2';

$link1 = connecttodb($servername,$dbname1,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
$link2 = connecttodb($servername,$dbname2,$dbusername,$dbpassword);

function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword)
{
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword",TRUE);
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    return $link;
}
    ?>
```

I display result in result.php with this code:

```
<?
require "connect1.php"; 

$q=mysql_query("select * from table1 where username='test' order by id",link1);

while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo "$nt[location]";
}

?>
```

I would like to display similar data in result.php, but with connection to db2

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a single global $link variable, you need two:

```
$link1 = connecttodb($servername1,$dbname1,$dbusername1,$dbpassword1);
$link2 = connecttodb($servername2,$dbname2,$dbusername2,$dbpassword2);
```

And of course change connectodb() to:

```
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword",TRUE);
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    return $link;
}
```

Please note that i've added a fourth parameter to mysql_connect, stating TRUE for the new_link parameter (this will only be needed if the two databases reside on the same server).

Then, for each query you will have to specify the corresponding link variable (either $link1 or $link2) according to the database you wish to query.

Comment: @SašoKrajnc don't post code in comments, it gets difficult to read. Edit your question instead and add it there

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: NoticeMessage: Use of undefined constant link1 - assumed 'link1'Filename: result.phpLine Number: 211
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: WarningMessage: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resourceFilename: result.phpLine Number: 211
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: WarningMessage: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resourceFilename:result.phpLine Number: 213

Comment: Please note that you forgot the '$' in front of the $link variable when you passed it to mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect a second time, and this is crucial, keep the new handle in `$link2`. So you first need to add a new connect function, and I would advise creating the global variables via reference parameter now:

```
function connecttodb(&$link, $servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
   $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
   if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
   mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}

connecttodb($link1, $servername, $dbname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
connecttodb($link2, $servername2, $dbname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
```

You then need to carry around your $link1 and $link2 variables for the actualy queries:

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from table1 where username='test' order by id ", $link1);
```

Then do the same query again for $link2.
And at this point it might be best to investigage some loops for querying multiple databases, or a class which abstracts it away (if you generally query against two sources anyway).

---

Actually there is also a super-lazy option, if both tables are equivalent and running on the same server, just different database names. You could then append the query using UNION ALL:

```
 select * from table1 where username='test' order by id
 UNION ALL
 select * from db2.table1 where username='test' order by id
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Also don't post passwords. For code use backticks.  But don't post lengthy code into comments anyway, use the edit link on your question.